# Remove rows that do NOT contain a letter in them using R

Tags: r, regex, text, filter, data-cleaning

I'm trying to filter out my data, so I only contain rows with IDs that have at least one letter (in any place). I'm stumped because I have so many rows with random characters or random whitespaces, so even when I try to filter out on whitespace, it misses them.

Here's my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- tibble(id = c("   ", "91a", "90", "ab"),
               score = c(5, 10, 15, 91))
```

And here's what I want:

```
library(tidyverse)
answer <- tibble(id = c("91a","ab"),
               score = c(10, 91))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  :

```
subset(test, grepl('[a-zA-Z]', id))

#   id    score
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 91a      10
#2 ab       91
```

Or in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% filter(grepl('[a-zA-Z]', id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package to detect the presence of a pattern in the `id` variable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

test <- tibble(id = c("   ", "91a", "90", "ab"),
               score = c(5, 10, 15, 91))

filter(test, str_detect(id, '[a-zA-Z]'))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   id    score
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 91a      10
#> 2 ab       91
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>